# Different customizer previewUrls per section

Tags: theme-customizer

For example if there is a Customizer section that focuses on Woocommerce options, I'd like the user to be on the shop page for that, to see all these changes, live.

I can do http://127.0.0.1/wp-admin/customize.php?url=http://127.0.0.1/shop&autofocus[section]=woocommerce as a link in the admin panel, which will put customizer on that URL, with the relevant section open, but that's not ideal.

I would like the customizer to automatically navigate to the specified url when the user clicks on any section.

Is there any way to have onSectionClick event and then set previewUrl to something?

Comment: Whilst your intentions are innocent, I would argue this might be confusing/anti-user-friendly. By all means, use the [contextual logic in the customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#contextual-panels-sections-and-controls) to only _show_ sections/controls _when on the shop_, but don't do it the other way around. What if a user is customizing & flicking between sections? They click WooCommerce and _bam_, their preview window gets redirected to the shop - not necessarily what they wanted or intended to do.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `active_callback` property to delegate section visibility depending on current preview screen.

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'my-section',
array(
    'title' => __( 'Section Title' ),
    'active_callback' => 'is_shop',
) );
```

Or custom

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'my-section',
array(
    'title' => __( 'Section Title' ),
    'active_callback' => 'is_custom_condition',
) );
function is_custom_condition(){
    $condition_is_met = //Some boolean returning logic;
    if( ! $condition_is_met ){
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```